# Calling a javascript function in displaytag

Tags: struts2, struts, displaytag

How to call a javascript function in struts displaytag, i want to pass id into that javascript function.Iam not getting any idea any one help me..

```
<display:column style="text-align: center;" title="Booth No"
        property="partNo" />
```

here how can i call javascript function..

here is my code..

```
<div >
            <display:table id="boothResultsTableId"
                 name="${boothResult.perWiseboothResults}"
                defaultorder="ascending" defaultsort="4"
                style="width:auto;margin-left:1px;border:1px solid #C4DEFF;">

            <display:column style="text-align:center;" title="Polling % Range"
                    property="location" />
            <display:column style="text-align:center;" title="Total No of Booths"
                    property="votesEarned">
                    <div class="coverAll" 
                        onclick="alert('hi');">
                    </div>
            </display:column>
            <display:column style="text-align:center;" title="Party Votes %"
                    property="percentage" />
            </display:table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a javascript function WHEN ? When clicked ?

JSP

```
<display:column style="text-align: center;" title="Booth No" property="partNo" />
   <div class="coverAll" 
       onclick="alert('hi ! ID is ' + <s:property value="#attr.myTab.myId" />);">
      stuff inside the div
   </div>
</display:column>
```

CSS

```
.coverAll{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: put "javascript:" in front of "alert"

Answer (score 0):

`<display:column style="text-align: center;" title="Booth No"
        property="partNo" />`
  `<a onclick="fn(${row.id})">link</a>`
    `</display:column>`

where `row` is from `<display:table id="row"` ...

Answer (score 0):

Although I am new to STRUTS I read Andrea's post and used the `#attr.` value idea. This may be a hackers way of doing it, but it worked.

This is my `<display.column` code:

```
<display:column class="textBold8" property="supplierCd" style="color:black"
    paramId="supplierCd" paramProperty="supplierCd" titleKey="supplier.supplierCd"
    sortable="true" href="javascript:openSmallWin(\'#attr.supplier.supplierId\');//">
</display:column>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
function openSmallWin(s) {
    // The value of 's' is selected using a .substring method in order to isolate the    actual
    // value of the supplier code. What comes into the javascript function is 
    // '?supplierCd=xxxxxxxxx#attr.supplier.suplierId'.
    // Where xxxxxxxxx is the actual value of the Supplier Code. Sorry.     
    var theUrl = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/supplier.do? method=view&supplierCd="+s.substring(12,21);
    window.open(theUrl,"purchaseOrderWnd", 'resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=800,height=675')
}
```